# How can I disable "Scan for external changes" in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I disable "Scan for external changes" in netbeans ?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

By Unmarking the [checkbox as mentioned here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110513031753/http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/enable_auto_scanning_of_sources):

Go to menu: Tools/Options/Miscellaneous/Files => ❑ Enable auto-scanning of sources

Image from site
[image]

Comment: Can you expand your answer, please? The link may be broken in the future.

Answer (score 17):

> In Netbeans(Windows), Go to "Tools > Options > Miscellaneous/Files ", You will
>   find an option called "Enable auto-scanning of sources".

In case if you want to **manually refresh** (scan) your sources. Then right click the folder in Netbeans Projects window (or any explorere window like Favourites, Files, etc.,) you will find the option called 'Refresh Folder'.

*Note* : This option will be enabled only after you disabled the auto-scanning options.

Comment: Not working on 8.1. But It's work with block folder that you want scan external changes, then click on menu bar **Source > Scan for External Changes**.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac go to menu:
NetBeans/Preferences/Miscellaneous/Files and uncheck ❑ Enable auto-scanning of sources

Works for NetBeans version 8.0.2, MacOs 10.10.2 Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MAC Netbeans 8.1 and I dont have `NetBeans/Preferences/Miscellaneous/Files` Can someone help please? `checking external changes` is using all CPU

I dont have `Preferences` in my main menu

PS: I found my solution; I just mention it for others who run into the same issue ; just use this short key to open `Cmd-,` to open the menu: `NetBeans/Preferences/Miscellaneous/Files`