# disable sources scan for a specific folder in netbeans 7.1 RC2

Tags: netbeans

I'm having an issue with netbeans scanning a large directory of PHP files
The scan takes about 2 hours and totally blocks the IDE's autocompletion and slows it down a lot

I tried a few things:

- disabling auto-scanning of sources as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268031/how-can-i-disable-scan-for-external-changes-in-netbeans)
- adding the pattern of the files in the "Files ignored by the IDE" box
- adding the directory to the ignored folder list in my project properties

None of the above worked.

An idea anyone?

Comment: apparently the netbeans team have fixed this annoying bug in their 7.2 release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also might be able to ignore just some files from the automatic source scan.

See [netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand#Prevent_Rescan_on_Certain_Files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the "Tasks" tab to stop it.